# DMZ Setup Reality Check?

Tags: security

I'm currently doing some upgrades to servers and networking in our network and I'm looking for a reality check on our DMZ configuration.  I put it together quite a long time ago and I'm wondering if it's still relevant or if there's a better (more secure) way?

I'm thinking specifically of our webserver traffic.  We have numerous web applications that people need to access from outside our network.  Nearly all of them require some sort of access to our internal Active Directory and sometimes other internal services.

I always hated the thought of putting the webservers in the DMZ and punching holes back into the internal network for Active Directory and/or LDAP so rather than do that I setup a reverse proxy in the DMZ and proxied the web requests from the DMZ through on port 443/80 into the servers on the internal network (kinda like [this example](https://alemba.help/help/Content/resources/images/mobile%20app%20dmz%20proxy%20server_702x356.png)).  It's worked okay over the years, some applications work well with it, and others are a bit of a trial.

Anyway, before I go and upgrade a number of the servers in question (some are 2k8 R2, which is EOL soon) I thought I'd review it all.  I know there are other ways you can achieve this (like putting the webservers in the DMZ with an RODC for example).  I'm after some thoughts on whether I need to change my setup (and what an alternative might look like), or if it's still valid.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Proxy from a perimeter network to inside is still a good idea.

However, what the trusted perimeter concept lacks is that there are plenty of threats inside. Workstations get compromised, users go rogue and do bad things. Micro segmentation may help. Most users don't need to see LDAP or internal app traffic, so firewall it internally to only where needed. This requires some  maturity around security processes and tooling, different from an edge firewall and its rules.

For auth specifically, protocols exist for federated single sign on (SAML, OAuth) or auth over untrusted networks (Kerberos). Rather than bring your full directory to your perimeter, consider something like AD Federation Services that speaks the auth of web apps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, we don't have the option of changing any apps to support different auth. schemes, but I like the idea of (more) internal firewalling.